# Extract portion of image with transparent background

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I have a BufferedImage(any will do). I extract a sub-image.
Now I wish to define a region of interest within the sub-image,
and save my sub-image to another BufferedImage with all but the
region of interest transparent.

[image: Sub image without transparent]

So far I'm unable to make the region outside my region of
interest transparent. In the code below, the region I want
to be transparent is Area a1.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Image {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int rules[] = {
        AlphaComposite.DST_IN, AlphaComposite.DST_OUT,  AlphaComposite.DST_OVER,
        AlphaComposite.SRC_IN, AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, AlphaComposite.SRC_OUT,
        AlphaComposite.CLEAR };
    try {      

      int ac = rules[3];
      
      // Any image of the right size will do here. I'm just using this as a demo.d
      BufferedImage original = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://eskipaper.com/images/abstract-art-1.jpg"));
      BufferedImage sub = original.getSubimage(500, 400, 1050, 300);
      
      Rectangle2D.Double r1 = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 1050, 300);
      Area a1 = new Area(r1);
      Ellipse2D.Double e1 = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 1050, 300);
      Area a2 = new Area(e1);
      
      Graphics2D g3d = sub.createGraphics();
      
      g3d.setColor(new Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
      a1.subtract(a2);
      g3d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(rules[3], 1.0f));
      g3d.fill(a1);      
      
      ImageIO.write(sub, "png", new File("abstract-art-out.png"));
      
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just create a new `BufferedImage` of the size of the original and simply paint the sub image into it?

Comment: You're not starting with a transparent image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not starting with a transparent image (your source image is `jpg`, which doesn't tend to support transparency)

So, instead, you need to create an intermediate transparent image, for example...

```
BufferedImage transparentSub = new BufferedImage(sub.getWidth(), sub.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TRANSLUCENT);

Graphics2D g3d = transparentSub.createGraphics();
g3d.drawImage(sub, 0, 0, null);
```

So, with this modification in your original code...

```
int rules[] = {
    AlphaComposite.DST_IN, AlphaComposite.DST_OUT, AlphaComposite.DST_OVER,
    AlphaComposite.SRC_IN, AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, AlphaComposite.SRC_OUT,
    AlphaComposite.CLEAR};
try {

    int ac = rules[3];

    // Any image of the right size will do here. I'm just using this as a demo.d
    BufferedImage original = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://eskipaper.com/images/abstract-art-1.jpg"));
    BufferedImage sub = original.getSubimage(500, 400, 1050, 300);

    Rectangle2D.Double r1 = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 1050, 300);
    Area a1 = new Area(r1);
    Ellipse2D.Double e1 = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 1050, 300);
    Area a2 = new Area(e1);

    BufferedImage transparentSub = new BufferedImage(sub.getWidth(), sub.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TRANSLUCENT);

    Graphics2D g3d = transparentSub.createGraphics();
    g3d.drawImage(sub, 0, 0, null);

    g3d.setColor(new Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    a1.subtract(a2);
    g3d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(rules[3], 1.0f));
    g3d.fill(a1);
    g3d.dispose();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new ImageIcon(transparentSub));

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It now outputs...

[image]